# Exploration of State Space in NuSMV Source

Tags: model-checking, nusmv, binary-decision-diagram

I am working on a program correction/synthesis project. My task is to obtain an error trace (counter-example), locate it in the complete state space, and repair the model at that location. I want to implement this as a NuSMV extension.

I have been debugging NuSMV to understand and explore its source code. So far, I have found my way to the creation of the BDD FSM (compile.c line 520). I am trying to find a way to traverse the bdd in order to gain programmatic access to the state space, and thus perform my corrective work upon the model. I have not yet been able to understand the recursive exploration functions NuSMV uses to verify properties via the bdd fsm.

I would like to know how i can traverse the bdd structure so I can visualise it through tools like dot. I would also like to know if such or smilar visualisations have already been made (I have searched but come up empty). Secondly, I would like to verify whether the direction I have taken up is the right one, or if there is a better way to obtain the complete state space of a given model, and explore it, especially with regards to a counter-example obtained through NuSMV.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer about ways to work with binary decision diagrams (BDDs) using CUDD other than via NuSMV, so focusing on the question's second part.

About symbolic algorithms for investigating a state space, the paper ["Algorithmic verification of linear temporal logic specifications"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.42.6133) by Kesten, Pnueli, and Raviv (ICALP '98, DOI: [10.1007/BFb0055036](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0055036)) is a good introduction, which covers counterexample construction.

One possibility for visualizing BDDs is working in Python, using Cython bindings to CUDD:

```py
from dd import cudd


def dump_pdf_cudd():
    bdd = cudd.BDD()
    bdd.declare('x', 'y', 'z')
    u = bdd.add_expr(r'(x /\ y) \/ ~ z')
    bdd.dump('foo.pdf', [u])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dump_pdf_cudd()
```

This approach uses [`dd`](https://github.com/tulip-control/dd), which can be installed using [`pip`](https://github.com/pypa/pip), with `pip install dd`. Documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/tulip-control/dd/blob/master/doc.md). Looking at the (internal) module [`dd._abc`](https://github.com/tulip-control/dd/blob/master/dd/_abc.py) may also be informative (this serves as a specification; the name "abc" alludes to [abstract base classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) in Python).
(Pure Python suffices for smaller problems, and CUDD is useful for larger problems).

[image]

There are two kinds of traversals relevant to the question:

1. traversal of the graph of BDD
2. traversal of the graph that has states as nodes and steps as edges.

These are discussed separately below.

### Traversing the graph of a BDD

Depth-first traversal is more common than breath-first when working with BDDs.
For the interface of `dd.cudd` and `dd.autoref` such a traversal is:

```py
import dd.autoref as _bdd


def demo_bdd_traversal():
    bdd = _bdd.BDD()
    bdd.declare('x', 'y')
    u = bdd.add_expr(r'x /\ y')
    print_bdd_nodes(u)


def print_bdd_nodes(u):
    visited = set()
    _print_bdd_nodes(u, visited)


def _print_bdd_nodes(u, visited):
    # leaf ?
    if u.var is None:
        print('leaf reached')
        return
    # non-leaf
    # already visited ?
    if u in visited:
        return
    # recurse
    v = u.low
    w = u.high
    # DFS pre-order
    print(f'found node {u}')
    _print_bdd_nodes(v, visited)
    # DFS in-order
    print(f'back to node {u}')
    _print_bdd_nodes(w, visited)
    # DFS post-order
    print(f'leaving node {u}')
    # memoize
    visited.add(u)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo_bdd_traversal()
```

[Complemented edges](https://doi.org/10.1109/DAC.1990.114826) need also to be taken into account when working with BDDs (using CUDD or similar libraries). The attribute `u.negated` provides this information.

The function [`dd.bdd.copy_bdd`](https://github.com/tulip-control/dd/blob/7d5ab075d10631a0dbe746055a5dc955c0f48297/dd/bdd.py#L1758) is a pure Python example of traversing a BDD. This function manipulates BDDs directly through a "low level" interface that is wrapped by `dd.autoref` to look the same as `dd.cudd`.

### Traversal of a state graph

The script [`dd/examples/reachability.py`](https://github.com/tulip-control/dd/blob/master/examples/reachability.py) shows how to compute from which states a given set of states can be reached in a finite number of steps.

The package [`omega`](https://github.com/tulip-control/omega) is more convenient than `dd` for developing BDD-based algorithms related to system behaviors. The script [`omega/examples/reachability_solver`](https://github.com/tulip-control/omega/blob/master/examples/reachability_solver.py) demonstrates a reachability computation using `omega`.

A basic example of *forward* reachability using `omega == 0.3.1` follows:

```py
import omega.symbolic.temporal as trl
import omega.symbolic.prime as prm


def reachability_example():
    """How to find what states are reachable."""
    aut = trl.Automaton()
    vrs = dict(
        x=(0, 10),
        y=(3, 50))
    aut.declare_variables(**vrs)
    aut.varlist = dict(
        sys=['x', 'y'])
    aut.prime_varlists()
    s = r'''
        Init ==
            /\ x = 0
            /\ y = 45

        Next ==
            /\ (x' = IF x < 10 THEN x + 1 ELSE 0)
            /\ (y' = IF y > 5 THEN y - 1 ELSE 45)
        '''
    aut.define(s)
    init = aut.add_expr('Init', with_ops=True)
    action = aut.add_expr('Next', with_ops=True)
    reachable = reachable_states(init, action, vrs, aut)
    n = aut.count(reachable, care_vars=['x', 'y'])
    print(f'{n} states are reachable')


def reachable_states(init, action, vrs, aut):
    """States reachable by `action` steps, starting from `init`."""
    operator = lambda y: image(y, action, vrs, aut)
    r = least_fixpoint(operator, init)
    assert prm.is_state_predicate(r)
    return r


def image(source, action, vrs, aut):
    """States reachable from `source` in one step that satisfies `action`."""
    u = source & action
    u = aut.exist(vrs, u)
    return aut.replace_with_unprimed(vrs, u)


def least_fixpoint(operator, target):
    """Least fixpoint of `operator`, starting from `target`."""
    y = target
    yold = None
    while y != yold:
        yold = y
        y |= operator(y)
    return y


if __name__ == '__main__':
    reachability_example()
```

Comparing `omega` with `dd`:

- `omega` supports variables and constants, and integer values for these (the relevant module is [`omega.symbolic.temporal`](https://github.com/tulip-control/omega/blob/master/omega/symbolic/temporal.py)). Variables represent state changes, for example `x` and `x'`. Constants remain unchanged through a system's behavior.
- `dd` supports only Boolean-valued variables (`omega` uses Boolean-valued variables to represent integer-valued variables, and so represent predicates as BDDs via `dd`; the bitblasting is done in the module [`omega.logic.bitvector`](https://github.com/tulip-control/omega/blob/master/omega/logic/bitvector.py)).

Several fixpoint operators are implemented in [`omega.symbolic.fixpoint`](https://github.com/tulip-control/omega/blob/master/omega/symbolic/fixpoint.py). These operators can be used for model checking or [temporal synthesis](https://github.com/tulip-control/omega/blob/master/omega/games/gr1.py). The module `omega.logic.past` includes translations of temporal operators that are relevant to symbolic model checking (also known as [*temporal testers*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-69850-0_11)).

Documentation of `omega` can be found [here](https://github.com/tulip-control/omega/blob/master/doc/doc.md).

### Further comments

I used the term "step" above to refer to a pair of consecutive states that represents a change of state allowed by the specification. The TLA+ language, and steps, flexible and rigid variables, and other useful concepts are described in Leslie Lamport's book [Specifying Systems](https://lamport.azurewebsites.net/pubs/pubs.html#tla+-book).

A collection of formal verification software is listed at https://github.com/johnyf/tool_lists/.

In my experience, working at the Python level, with only the BDD manager at the C level, is an efficient approach that leads to readable code, and clearer algorithms.